# Angularjs passing arguments to uibmodal

Tags: angularjs

creation

```
           let modalInstance = this.$uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'showTemplateContent.html',
                controller: 'ShowTemplateContentController',
                controllerAs: 'modal',
                resolve: {
                    hoveredItem: () => {
                        return hoveredItem;
                    }
                }
            });
```

template

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-header" ng-mouseleave="close()">
        title:
        <h3 class="modal-title"> {{hoveredItem.templateName}} </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        content:
        {{hoveredItem.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
namespace app.view.modal {

export interface IShowTemplateContentController{
    modal: ShowTemplateContentController
    $resolve: any
    hoveredItem: any
}

export class ShowTemplateContentController {
    constructor(private $scope: IShowTemplateContentController,
                private $uibModalInstance,
    ) {
        this.$scope.modal = this;
        console.log(this.$scope.hoveredItem);
        this.init()
    }

    init() {
        this.$scope.hoveredItem = this.$scope.$resolve.hoveredItem;
    }

    close(reason: string) {
        this.$uibModalInstance.dismiss(reason);
    };
}
}
```

The modal appears with only content and id without showing whats inside the interpolation. Also this does not print the hoveredItem in console either. I am not familiar with this kind of angularjs syntax. How can I use hoveredItem in my template and controller? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing `hoveredItem` into resolve, you need to inject it in the modal controller:

```
constructor(hoveredItem, private $uibModalInstance) {

    console.log(hoveredItem);
}
```

You have also used:

```
controllerAs: 'modal',
```

So, in html use modal as reference to controller:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    content:
    {{ modal.hoveredItem.content }}
</div>
```